# Complex operations with Python (pygame.math.Vector2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, tuples

I'm learning Python and came across a complex expression that derives from `pygame.Vector2`:

```
import pygame
x = pygame.math.Vector2 (1,2)
b = x * 5 - (1, 2)
print (x)
print (b)
```

Result:

```
[1,2]
[4,8]
```

In the above case, the same `x * 5` operation is performed both for the `1` and `2` values of `Vector2`, resulting in (5, 10) respectively; and then both results are subtracted from the tuple `(1, 2)`, resulting in [4,8]

However if I do assign a simple tuple to x: `x = (1, 2)`, instead of `Vector2`, I get the error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type (s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

My question is: **At what times in Python I can perform these complex operations?**

Comment: The `Vector2` class implements a `__mul__()` method that takes integers (among other types), and a `__sub__()` method that takes tuples.  Neither of these happened automatically, the implementor of the class thought that it was worth the extra effort to implement these features.  (Note that tuples couldn't reasonably implement the subtraction operation you tried to use, as it's incompatible with what addition of tuples does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do something like (see comments too):

```
x = (1,2) # create a `tuple`
b = map(lambda x: x * 5,x) # do a `map` object for multiplying 5 to all of them
print(x) # print the `tuple`
t=iter((1,2)) # do an generator object using `iter`, so able to use `next` to access every next element
print(tuple(map(lambda x: x-next(t),b))) # do the `next` and another `map`, to subtract as you wanted
```

Best thing is still to create a class:

```
from __future__ import division
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self,t):
      self.t=t
   def __mul__(self,other):
      return MyClass(tuple(map(lambda x: x*other,self.t)))
   def __truediv__(self,other):
      return MyClass(tuple(map(lambda x: x/other,self.t)))
   def __sub__(self,other):
      gen=iter(other)
      return MyClass(tuple(map(lambda x: x-next(gen),self.t)))
   def __add__(self,other):
      gen=iter(other)
      return MyClass(tuple(map(lambda x: x+next(gen),self.t)))
   def __repr__(self):
      return str(tuple(self.t))
```

Then now can do anything:

```
x = MyClass((1,2))
b = x*5
print(b)
print(b-(1,2))
```

Output:

```
(5, 10)
(4, 8)
```

Also can do addition:

```
x = MyClass((1,2))
b = x*5
print(b)
print(b-(1,2)+(3,4))
```

Output:

```
(5, 10)
(7, 12)
```

Also division:

```
x = MyClass((1,2))
b = x*5
print(b)
print((b-(1,2)+(3,4))/2)
```

Output:

```
(5, 10)
(3.5, 6.0)
```